# sum and count query in columns

Tags: sql

i count 3 columns and than i want sum after count 3 columns

table name is bill

```
-----------------------------------------------
order_id1 | order_id2 | order_id3  |  sum(orders)
-----------------------------------------------
  4       |      3    |    1       |      8
```

what is query for solving this?

i wrote this query but give me 0

```
select count (order_id1 + order_id2 + order_id3) 
from bill 
where (order_id1 + order_id2 + order_id3) =1‏
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an unambiguous database tag, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using an aggregation function.  It looks like you want to sum three columns.  That would be:

```
select b.*, (order_id1 + order_id2 + order_id3) as total
from bill ;
```

Filtering is not mentioned in your question, so I don't know why there is a `where` clause.

Comment: sorry i wrote rows it's coulmns sorry

Comment: @sam . . . I figured that out.  You don't need the `SUM()` function.  `+` does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want single `order`s if so, you can use `not exists` :

```
select b.*
from bill b
where not exists (select 1 from bills b1 where b1.orderid = b.orderid and b.? <> b1.?);
```

`?` presents unique (`identity`) column available in `bill` table.